# Is there a fundamental difference in the way we think while writing when compared to speaking?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, consciousness, language, decision-making

I had a discussion with my friend recently about slip-ups in speech - the ones where you intented a gramatically correct sentence but somewhere between the conscious mind and your mouth a (usually small but often times a rather unexpected) mistake occurs.

My question is whether this phenomenon arises in the same way in the brain (what happens?) as a analogous mistake in writing, where one might for example mistype a letter, or put one too many bellies on a 'B' etc. Or in an even broader view, how does this compare to mistakes in a well trained movement, e.g. while playing a guitar a finger escapes its well-intentioned, and many times practised passage to an unexpected fret?

Comment: This is an interesting question.  Can someone with an extreme case of Tourettes such as [Ryan Stevens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uw06dMWfIuc) have the same problem with their writing?  [It seems that it is possible](https://www.tourette.org/resource/handwriting-issues/)